# Dynamic Wildcard settings in Tomcat Server.xml (Non www)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, server, server.xml

For example.com, the **appBase** for

a) **www.example.com** & **example.com** is `/home/example/public_html/e` - A wordpress site.

b) any other ***.example.com** is `/home/example/public_html` - A Java web app.

To achieve this, in **server.xml**, I am maintaining the following

a) For www & example.com

```
<Host name="example.com" appBase="/home/example/public_html/e" ...>
<Alias>www.example.com</Alias>
...
</Host>
```

b) For other wildcards, the following is **NOT WORKING**

```
<Host name="*.example.com" appBase="/home/example/public_html" ...>
...
</Host>
```

So, as a **workaround**, I have to **MANUALLY ADD** this whenever a,b,c etc are dynamically registered by the customers. Everytime requiring a Tomcat restart.

```
<Host name="*.example.com" appBase="/home/example/public_html" ...>
<Alias>a.example.com</Alias>
<Alias>b.example.com</Alias>
<Alias>c.example.com</Alias>    
...
</Host>
```

**MY QUESTION**

Since the wildcards are dynamically generated at client registration, how do I **dynamically set** in server.xml such that the **manual entry** & **Tomcat restart can be avoided**.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how at the moment is to specify the default host in server.xml

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="default-host">
```

and then later on in the file you can specify all requests to go to a specific host

```
<Host name="example-site">
        <Context path="" docBase="/home/example/public_html/e" />
        <Alias>example.com</Alias>
        <Alias>www.example.com</Alias>
      </Host>

      <Host name="registered-customers">
        <Context path="" docBase="/home/example/public_html" />
        <Alias>default-host</Alias>
      </Host>
```

Good luck :)